# Using Java Reflection to load Interfaces

Tags: java, reflection, interface

Can someone please guide me on this. I have a class loader which I could load a class using Java reflection. However, is there anyway I can cast my object to an interface? I understand that there is a `ServiceLoader` but I read it is highly not recommended.

```
//returns a class which implements IBorrowable
public static IBorrowable getBorrowable1()  
{
    IBorrowable a;  //an interface
     try
        {
            ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            a = (IBorrowable) myClassLoader.loadClass("entityclasses.Books");

        }
    catch (Exception e ){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You need to invoke `newInstance()` on the returned class before casting it. This of course assumes you have a default constructor on the actual class.

Comment: @StephenC - his exception handling is indeed horrible, but thats not the problem with his current code.

Comment: I just realised.  I'm too tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing an object instantiation.

`myClassLoader.loadClass("entityclasses.Books")` does *not* return an instance of `IBorrowable`, but an instance of Class object, that refers to Books. You need to create an instance of the loaded class using `newInstance()` method

Here is fixed version (assuming, `Books` has default constructor)

```
public static IBorrowable getBorrowable1()  //returns a class which implements IBorrowable
{
     try {
        ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        Class<IBorrowable> clazz = (IBorrowable) myClassLoader.loadClass("entityclasses.Books");
        return clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see that you might be doing wrong here is using the system classloader. The chances are it won't be able to see your implementation class.

```
public static IBorrowable getBorrowable1()  //returns a class which implements IBorrowable
{
    IBorrowable a;  //an interface
     try
        {
            a = (IBorrowable) Class.forName("entityclasses.Books");
        }
    catch (Exception e ){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    return a;
}
```

As an aside `ServiceLoader` for me is highly recommended.